# how to let the size of array to grow and shrink automatically?

Tags: java

```
            int filename = 100;
    String[] fileName = new String[filename];
    int a = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;

    // Count the number of documents containing the query

    System.out.println("Please enter the query  :");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word2 = scan2.nextLine();
    String[] array2 = word2.split(" ");
    int[] numofDoc = new int[array2.length];

    for (int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {

        numofDoc[b] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < filename; i++) {

            try {

                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\user\\fypworkspace\\FYP\\abc"
                                + i + ".txt"));

                int matchedWord = 0;

                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(bf);

                {

                    while (s2.hasNext()) {
                        if (s2.next().equals(array2[b]))
                            matchedWord++;
                    }

                }
                if (matchedWord > 0)
                    numofDoc[b]++;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        _resultArea.append(array2[b]
                + " --> This number of files that contain this term  "
                + numofDoc[b]+ newline);
    }
```

hi, this is my code for calculating number of files that contain a specific input keyed in by the user. This code analyze a folder of text files and search the text files whether it has the input or not. 
The problem i facing now is, i now declaring the array size of 100. It means that it will process 100 text files whether the folder have 100 files or not. **How do i let the program to process exact number of text files inside a folder ?**

Note : The number of text files is dynamic. It doesnt has a constant number of text files inside the folder.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `java.io.File.list()`, and use a `List`.

For example:

```
File[] files = dir.list();
List<File> list = new LinkedList<File>();
for (File f : files) {
    if (/* f matches our criteria */) {
        list.add(f);
    }
}
```

If you need an array after that, do this:

```
File[] array = list.toArray(new File[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are of static size. You should use a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (whose most frequently used implementation is [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) instead, which can grow and shrink dynamically and safely. Not to mention that (since Java 5) it is generic, i.e. typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

Either keep track of the number of text files you read, or use a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which has a size property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a List like

```
 List<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or you could just maintain the count of files you have

```
 for (int i = 0; i < filenameCount; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I am pretty sure you could use [arraylist](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)